# Problem trying to run function inside another function in an if conditional

Tags: javascript

Hello i want to run the confetti function that is INSIDE setStatusClass() so everytime i clicked the correct answer it runs confetti, but it runs even when wrong answer is click can someone let me know how to fix this?

```
**function setStatusClass(element,correct){
    clearStatusClass(element)
    if(correct){
        element.classList.add('correct') 
        confetti();
    }else{
        element.classList.add('wrong')
        
        
    }
}**

function clearStatusClass(element){
    element.classList.remove('correct')
    element.classList.remove('wrong')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the `correct` variable is always 'valid' so the logic always goes to that.
Try investigating what `correct` value is, eg: `console.log(correct)`. then write a more specific condition.